# Recaptcha v2 not respond

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm trying to create a simple mail function with recaptcha v2, but unfortunately it seems like the Recaptcha v2 is not responding and error show "Verification failed". Possible the recaptcha secretkey and sitekey wrong? Anyone could please let me know which coding parts are wrong.

Html Code

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">

  <h4 class=""><?= $msg;?></h4>

  <div>
    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off" required/>
    </div>

   <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" required/>
   </div>

   <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
     <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" value="" placeholder="Contact Number" autocomplete="off"  oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" required/>
   </div>

   <div class="col-12">
    <select name="model" id="model" required>
     <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">- Mercedes Model-</option>
     <option value="CLA">CLA</option>
     <option value="AMG">AMG</option>
     <option value="SUV">SUV</option>
    </select>
   </div>

   <div class="col-12">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6" required style="resize: none;"/></textarea>
   </div>

  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey; ?>"></div> <br/>
    <ul class="actions">
    <button><input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Send Message" class="primary" /></button>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

send email

```
<?php
$siteKey    = '******';

error_reporting(0);
$msg="";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
  $subject = "Form Submission";
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
  $model= $_POST['model'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $msgBody = "
    <h2>Contact Request Details</h2>
    <p><b>Name: </b>".$name."</p>
    <p><b>Email: </b>".$email."</p>
    <p><b>Phone Number: </b>".$phoneNumber."</p>
    <p><b>Model: </b>".$model."</p>
    <p><b>Message: </b>".$message."</p>
  ";

  $headers = 'From:' .$email;

  $secretKey    = '******';
  $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

  $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey";

  $response = file_get_contents($url);
  $response = json_decode($response);

  if($response->success){
    if(mail($to, $subject,$msgBody,$header)){
      $msg="Message sent successfully";
    }else{
      $msg="Failed to send the mssage";
    }
  }
  else{
    $msg="Verification Failed";
  }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Can you please show us how you import JS library for Google reCaptcha and all the JS code for that?

Comment: @quarky, sorry for the late reply. I didn't import any JS library file. I just using the link <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script> with posted code only. Am I missing something?